# Python, Service dies but PID remains.. Log file updates every minute

Tags: python

I have service that as the topic says dies and leave a stale PID behind. This particular service logs every minute. So basically I want to create a python script to check the logfile based on modified time, if file has not updated in say 3 minutes then restart service.

I am new to scripting / programming so I need help with the logic here please...

this is what I have so far to do the check on the file age.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, datetime, time

from os import path
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
#file = "/var/log/file.log"

def check_file(seconds, file_name):

    try:
        time_diff  = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds)
        file_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(path.getctime(file_name))
        if file_time < time_diff:
            return [True, "File: %s. Older than: %s, file_time:%s , date_diff:%s " % (file_name, seconds, file_time, time_diff)]
        else:
            return [True, "File: %s. Older than: %s, file_time:%s , date_diff:%s " % (file_name, seconds, file_time, time_diff)]

    except Exception, e:
        return [False, e]
```

Answer (score 0):

Before writing custom code to handle this problem (and now having 2 problems), I'd look at:

1. fixing the service itself so that it doesn't die,
2. adding monitoring to that service at the box level (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/683325/linux-to-monitor-a-service-and-restart-if-stopped)
   for example).

If these options are not practical, I would start with a bash based solution over Python.

In either case, you'll need to make sure that the restarting script doesn't die either.